# Mediawiki: creating a table with automatic numeration

Tags: loops, mediawiki

I'm using Mediawiki and I'm presently struggeling with creating a table with automatic numeration. 
Right now I have about 50 pages wihich belong to a naming concept (let's call it) .TEST. 
I'm getting a list of all my pages with this query:

```
{{#ask: [[Category:Server]] [[N-Segment::TEST]]  
|?IPs
}}
```

Mediawiki outputs me a table with all pages and the attributes I want.

```
Bla.TEST        10.0.0.1  
test2.TEST      10.0.0.2
another.TEST    10.0.0.64
.
.
last.TEST       10.0.0.210
```

Additionally I desire a column, which shows me the present number in each row just like the following example:

```
1    Bla.TEST        10.0.0.1
2    test2.TEST      10.0.0.2
3    another.TEST    10.0.0.64
4
. 
.
50   last.TEST       10.0.0.210
```

I have already searched for this but I couldn't found any suitable solution.
How can I achieve my goal?
Additional information: I'm using Mediawiki version `1.23.1`.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable with Extension:Variables (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables) which allows you to keep values between template calls. You will have to use Semantic MediaWikis template output format though.

Comment: I didn't even think anyone would answer :D Could you give me an example of your solution, please?

Comment: Well... At first I was happy because of this solution. But this method is a bit statically, too. Did I get his explaination right? Do I need to define a viable on all my pages? If yes, this solution isn't what I was searching. I mean, if I delete a page I need to correct all my other pages, too.

Comment: If in SMW you use the template format, you can have an introtemplate, an outrotemplate and a template to do the rows, the introtemplate your vardefine the variable, the row template would vardefineecho the variable and define it one bigger. You can do simple math with the expr  parser function of the ParserFunctions extension

Comment: Look at http://wiki.teamliquid.net/rocketleague/index.php?title=User:FO-nTTaX/Sandbox/10&oldid=60469 and its related pages for an example